# How to avoid code repetition and redundancy

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to simplify some code which does the following:

- create one empty list where to store the information scraped from one website
- apply a function to fill the list
- add these information in a dataframe
- repeat the process selecting element not scraped yet

The process looks like

```
list1 = []

def fun(df):
    for x in df['Col']: 
        url = "my_website"+x
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
...
        list1.append(data1)
    return list1

list1 = fun(my_df)

my_df['List1'] = list1
```

(I tried to keep the code as simpler as possible)
The output looks like (the column `Col` is my initial dataframe, i.e. `my_df`):

```
Col          List1
mouse   [dog, horse, cat]   
horse   [mouse, elephant]   
tiger   []
```

Then, I repeat the process for strings in the list for each row:

```
# 2nd round
list1 = []
my_df2 = my_df.explode('List1')
my_list2 = pd.Series(list(set(my_df2['List1']) - set(my_df['Col'])), name='Col')
new_df2 = pd.DataFrame(my_list2, columns=['Col'])

list1 = fun(new_df2)

new_df2['List1'] = list1
```

Then I have another dataframe with other values, so I append these results to my original dataframe, `my_df`

```
my_df2= my_df.append(new_df2)
```

I repeat again the process

```
# 3rd round
list1 = []
my_df3 = my_df2.explode('List1')
my_list3 = pd.Series(list(set(my_df3['List1']) - set(my_df2['Col'])), name='Col')
new_df3 = pd.DataFrame(my_list3, columns=['Col'])

list1 = fun(new_df3)

new_df3['List1'] = list1
```

and so on, until I have finished to scrape all the data.

Since I am repeating these 'rounds' every time manually, I would like to ask you if there is a way to simplify the code in order to avoid all these awful repetition.
Any tips will be appreciated.

EDIT: my difficulties are in setting a condition where, if I have my original dataset, i.e. before creating the column List1, then create the empty list list1 then apply fun to my dataset.

In the other steps, I should:

- Initialise again the list1 in order to get a new dataframe from the list1 by exploding the column in my original (now update) dataset)
- Calculate the difference between this new dataframe and the previous one, to remove duplicates
- Run again the fun, storing the results in a column List1
- Append the results to the dataframe updated (which would be always the previous dataframe)
- repeat again the process.

If you need more information, I will be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from `my_df`, the list1 declaration should be inside `fun`, or you're emptying it elsewhere.

First, I would change `fun` to only work on one entry (not whole Series):

```
def fun(x):
    list1 = []
    url = "my_website"+x
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    ...
    list1.append(data1)
    return list1
```

Then, you can do the first transformation (populating second column List1) by doing:

```
my_df['List1'] = my_df.Col.apply(lambda x: fun(x))
```

After that, you could do something like:

```
while scraping_to_do:
     newCol = pd.Series(list(set(my_df['List1']) - set(my_df['Col'])))
     newList1 = newCol.apply(lambda x: fun(x))
     my_df = my_df.append(pd.DataFrame(dict('Col'=newCol, 'List1'=newList1)), ignore_index=True)
     my_df = my_df.explode('List1')
```

You need to figure out when to stop scraping (when the set difference is the empty set?), as well as deal with the NaNs that `explode` produces from empty lists.

Comment: unfortunately there is something that does not work properly in your code as I am getting something like this `([[dog, horse, cat]])` and not a list like this `[dog, horse, cat]`. Could you please tell me how to fix it? I am not understanding what is causing the issue. I think the solution would be flatten the list, but I would like to have already the list from the code above, instead of doing in a different step outside the function.  thanks a lot

Comment: This would depend on what exactly you're extracting from the website. You might need to change `fun` to always output a list like [[dog, horse, cat], [mouse], []]. In your original code, what was the output of `fun(my_df)`?