# Getting a list (and not a list of lists) within a code

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to transform a list of lists into a simple list.
Currently I have (wrong output):

```
Col          List1
mouse   ([[dog, horse, cat]])
horse   ([[mouse, elephant]])   
tiger   ([[]],[[]])
```

I would like to have

```
Col          List1
mouse   [dog, horse, cat]   
horse   [mouse, elephant]   
tiger   []
```

Code to create the first list above (and that needs to be updated accordingly in order to fix the issue) is

```
def alexa(x):
        surnames, score_lists = [],[]

   ...
      
        surnames.append(my_surname)
        score_lists.append(scores)
        return surnames, score_lists

surnames, score_lists = my_function(df)

df['Surname'] = df.Name.apply(lambda x: my_function(x))
df['Score'] = df.Name.apply(lambda x: my_function(x))
```

(more information in this post: [How to avoid code repetition and redundancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864016/how-to-avoid-code-repetition-and-redundancy))

I have tried as follows:

import itertools

```
list_surnames=list(itertools.chain(* surnames))
list_scores=list(itertools.chain(* score_lists))
```

However it seems to be wrong.
If you have any idea on how I can ge the expected output above, it would be great.

Comment: You can get the inner list just by getting the element at zero index.
`list[0]`

Comment: thanks @ahmadjanan. How could I get it and include this selection in my code? I feel I am missing the step where I should apply it

Comment: Are you adding data to data-frame from an array of arrays?

Comment: Initially no, so it was working fine and I was getting just a list. Then, when I used the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864016/how-to-avoid-code-repetition-and-redundancy I have got an array of arrays. But I am not understanding what is causing this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
import numpy as np

df["List1"] = df["List1"].apply(np.ravel)
#     Col              List1
#0  mouse  [dog, horse, cat]
#1  horse  [mouse, elephant]
#2  tiger                 []
```